Safe Factory v4 gives Invalid Account error when trying to initialize factory
This is the code
const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.init({
            provider: rpcUrl,
            signer: signerAddress
});

This is the error
Error: invalid account
    at JsonRpcProvider.getSigner

The intention is to be able to use the safe factory with a hardware wallet and run the code as a script (no UI). It worked in previous versions of the safe SDK.

You will need to use either an EIP-1193 provider as the provider, or a private key as the signer (not the address). You can not use a string provider and a string address at the same time.
Hope it answers your question! Best, Louis
